# AJAX/PHP - Accessing JSON object properties

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json

I'm attempting to access the properties of a JSON object. My ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'login.php',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $('#frmLgn').serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data[0].message);
    console.log(data[1].message);
    console.log(data[2].message);
}
```

The PHP is:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $queryMsgCntResults; $i++) {

  $queryGetNew = "SELECT message, msgID FROM $username WHERE isNew = 1;";
  try
  {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($queryGetNew);
    $stmt->execute();
    $message = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $messageArray[] = $message;         
  } 
  catch(PDOException $ex)
  {
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
  }     
}
echo json_encode($messageArray);
}
```

I am expecting this to output:

```
    console.log(data[0].message); //contents of message1
    console.log(data[1].message); //contents of message2
    console.log(data[2].message); //contents of message3
```

But instead get:

```
    console.log(data[0].message); //contents of message1
    console.log(data[1].message); //contents of message1
    console.log(data[2].message); //contents of message1
```

What am I missing/messing up?

Please close this question. I'm going to re-organize, re-test, and quite likely re-post for clarity. I appreciate all of your assistance, and apologize for wasting anyone's time. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure $messageArray is correct? Have you tried adding a print_r() to make sure?

Comment: In your `for` loop, you are running the *same query* over and over.  Every time, you are getting the *same* results.

Comment: As your line "$message = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);" you are getting just the current row instead a rows array, first you must to iterate your result and store it on a array, and the sent this array to json

Comment: Where is `$username` set?  Also, if you are using PDO, why are you concatenating the `$username` variable into the SQL string?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - I have additional PHP code within the same for loop that unsets the isNew flag, so once the first query is run, it won't return the same message. Sorry!

Comment: @RocketHazmat - $username is set earlier in the script, I didn't post the complete code. It's basically a login script that authenticates a user and checks for new messages. The login works, so it just appears to be an issue with either how I'm returning the data from sql or from php to ajax.

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This line gets one row at a time.  You need to keep calling it over and over to get every row.

```
while($message = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $messageArray[] = $message;
}
```

Comment: @user2442072 this is the code block that I have commented before

Comment: I have additional code that that unsets the isNew flag, so the first iteration of the for loop retrieves the message and sets the isNew flag to 0, so on the second iteration, that message is not returned. I tried adding the additional code, but SO said I had too much code.

Comment: Then paste your code or something close for help you, cause as your post that your are requesting is a array results instead a simple row, and you need just a row, you just need "no iteration"